# re-adding HTML into a DIV using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi All I have the following Div as seen below:

```
<div id = '1'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />                      
    </div>
</div>
```

when the user clicks on the button, I want to add the following Divs again:

```
        <div>
            <div>
                <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
            </div>
             <div>
                <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
             </div>
        </div>
```

Is this possible to achieve with JavaScript or the jQuery `onclick` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method with [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):

HTML:

```
<div id='1'>
    <div class="template"> <!-- mark a clone target -->
        ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VcBrz/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divID='abc';
    var $mainDiv=$('#'+divID);
    $mainDiv.find('input[name="addNewRow"]').eq(0).click(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var $div=$(this).parents('div').eq(0).prev('div').clone();
        $this.parents('div').eq(0).prev('div').after($div);
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xT62m/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the jquery append functionality https://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$('#1').append(html);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZqQAu/1/

Comment: could I have the full line please, would I have to write out every single line?

Comment: going to clean up my answer a bit, give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to clone that `div` which you want to add to `div#1`.

For easier manipulation, please add classes to `div` with button and to each `div` which represents row.

HTML:

```
<div id = 'id1'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='buttonHolder'>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.buttonHolder input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
        //Clone existing row to template.
        var row = $('#id1 .row').first().clone(); 

        //Clear template
        $('input', row).val('');    

        $(row).insertBefore('.buttonHolder input[type=button]');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Z2RT/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z2RT/1/)

Comment: In reality these divs are tied to classes could I do the same using ID?

Comment: also you can use `data` attributes (for example `data-row=1`, then in selector use `$('div[data-row]')`(selects all divs, which has that attribute or `$('div[data-row=value]')` selects all divs, that has that attribute and attbitue is equal to `value`.

Answer (score 0):

make html like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div class= 'template'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" id="btnAddRow" value="Add Row" />                      
</div>
```

Click Function:

```
$('#btnAddRow').click(function(){


var row = $('.template').first().clone();

$('#container').append(row);

});
```

Here is [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCWwD/)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <script>
            var m_TextToAdd = '<div> ';
            m_TextToAdd += '<div> ';
            m_TextToAdd += '    <label class="right inline">Response:</label>';
            m_TextToAdd += '</div>';
            m_TextToAdd += '<div>';
            m_TextToAdd += '    <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" /> ';
            m_TextToAdd += '</div>';
            m_TextToAdd += ' <div>';
            m_TextToAdd += '    <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />';
            m_TextToAdd += ' </div>';
            m_TextToAdd += '</div>';
            function AddContent() {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += m_TextToAdd;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'div1'>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" onclick='AddContent();'/>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyhow, it heart my eyes to see it :-) 
I think the next code is more readable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function AddContent() {
                var dest = document.getElementById('div1');
                //add label
                var lbl = document.createElement('label');
                lbl.innerHTML = 'Response:';
                lbl.className = 'right inline';
                dest.appendChild(lbl);
                //add line break
                dest.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                //add text input
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'text';
                input.name = 'responseText[]';
                input.maxlength="400";
                dest.appendChild(input);
                //add line break
                dest.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                //add radio button
                input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type="radio";
                input.name="responseRadio[]";
                dest.appendChild(input);
                //add line break
                dest.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'div1'>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
            <br>
            <input class='nextLine' type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />                          
            <br>
            <input class='nextLine' type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />                          
            <br>
            <input class='nextLine' type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" onclick='AddContent();'/>                      
            <br>
    </body>
</html>
```